# Prism with Unity wrong instance gets passed into constructor

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism, ioc-container

I am trying to understand/learn Prism with Unity

I created following classes:

==========================================

Seperate Assembly containing a "Module":

```
using GlobalContracts;
using Prism.Ioc;
using Prism.Modularity;

namespace ModuleA
{
  [Module(ModuleName = MyModuleA.NAME, OnDemand = true)]
  public class MyModuleA : IModule
  {
    public const string NAME = "MyModuleA";
    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
      containerRegistry.Register<MyControlA>();
      containerRegistry.Register<IView, MyControlA>(NAME);
      containerRegistry.Register<PluginViewModelBase, MyControlViewModel>(NAME);
    }

    public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

==========================================

A ViewModel

```
using GlobalContracts;

namespace ModuleA
{
  public class MyControlViewModel : PluginViewModelBase
  {
    public MyControlViewModel(IView view) : base(view)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

==========================================

The Host Application (other assembly):

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
  {
    private Shell mShell;
    private ShellViewModel mShellViewModel;

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
      return new DirectoryModuleCatalog(){ModulePath = @"..\..\..\..\ModulesOutput"};
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
      containerRegistry.Register<IView, Shell>();
      containerRegistry.Register<IViewModel, ShellViewModel>();
    }

    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
      mShellViewModel = Container.Resolve<ShellViewModel>();
      mShell = (Shell)mShellViewModel.View;
      return mShell;
    }
(...)
```

Now my question is:

- How do I tell Prism to resolve the IView-Parameter passed to the
  constructor of the ViewModel properly?

It resolves it as "Shell" and not as "MyControlA".

Further tips regarding my code are welcome

I found some sources in the web but they used "RegisterType" method of a container. And for now I do not have dependencies to Unity in my ModuleA and I would not know how to get the container to call the "RegisterType". All sources are outdated in the web..

Comment: Why would you want to pass the view to the view model?

Comment: The guy in the Plurasight online training did it as well. I think its because if you choose the ViewModel-first approach, you just create your ViewModel and the Framework resolves automatically your view. I thought the same as I saw him doing it.

Answer (score 0):

By default, it resolves the default registration, which in your case is `Shell`.

Registering a type with a name does not mean that that name is automatically used to resolve dependencies. You have to do that manually, with parameter override, injection factory or the like. But I'd try to avoid that as it makes things a bit fragile and tedious.

Comment: How do I avoid that?

Comment: Avoid what? It always resolves the default registration, unless you tell it to use a specific named one with parameter override.